# Time Difference between two date fusion transportation Intelligence (analytics)

Tags: cloud, obiee, oracle-bi

I try to get the time difference (in minutes for example) between two dates in the Fusion Transportation Intelligence (OTM FTI Cloud).
The format of date is : dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss (type : TIMESTAMP)

Oracle Business Intelligence Product Version 12.2.1.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

The function is TIMESTAMPDIFF - https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/bi12214/biee/BIESQ/toc.htm#BIESQ415